# MVC3 project will not execute pages with periods in the url on IIS6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, mime-types

I am getting a 404 error on my site when I upload it to our test server.  I've found that the issue lies in the url format.

`http://servername/Wizard/Review/B00557.0001`  if I manually encode the decimal to `%46` it works.  I guess IIS6.0 is trying to interpret B00557.0001 as a file.

I get this error code in my log file.

`2011-11-01 12:53:01 W3SVC259463726 10.90.10.11 GET /Wizard/Review/B00557.0001 - 80 - 10.90.10.32 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+InfoPath.2;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+MS-RTC+LM+8) 404 0 3`

Is there a server setting I can change to resolve this without modifying my applications code?

Comment: Did you configure wildcard mapping in IIS6?  I assume you did, but it never hurts to check.

Comment: I did after you said something about it.  what file should be mapped?  Currently I have `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll` but it is still not working

Comment: That is the correct file for .Net 4, so that did not fix the problem.  I expect the issue is that IIS6 is regarding `.0001` as an extension, for which it has no mapping.  What if you add a slug at the end, e.g., `http://servername/Wizard/Review/B00557.0001/some-text-here`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@counsellorben was correct for the most part. Verify file exists must be unchecked.  Since the url does not actually represent a physical file.

[image]

Comment: D'oh!  I always forget to mention that.  It is so ingrained for me to just uncheck that box, it's almost Pavlovian.